# Is there any way to set authorization status of CLLocationManager programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have two customized buttons like "Allow" and "Don't Allow" to access the location services of an app. When user tap on "Don't Allow" I want to set authorization status as  kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted or kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied. Is it possible?

Comment: If you can provide more info on why you want to do this then a good solution can be recommended. Basically what you want to set is already set  by the system when you choose the button. So wondering why you want to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### no.

iOS sets the authorization - you can only ask for it.

the whole idea of apps not tracking a user against there will would be void if your idea worked.